# Flattening and itemized lists

Tags: raku

```
> .say for flat $(8, 76)
8
76

> .say for flat ($(8, 76),)
(8 76)
```

I convinced myself it is not the single argument rule but what do I know. Question is why the itemized list is being flattened in the first case? I expected it not to be as in the second case. I tried to track down this [line](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/168da39ae24b84f78525280a8d6750dd3cf1a176/src/core.c/Iterable.pm6#L20) (which I think is called) but not sure what's going on there.

> Welcome to ™ v2021.07.
> Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d.
> Built on MoarVM version 2021.07.